# See my post's new likes (or see likes in chronological order)

Tags: facebook

- Day 1 morning: I post something on my personal Facebook wall.
- Day 1 evening: 200 likes, I check them quickly because I am interested in seeing who among my friends have liked my post.
- Day 2 morning: 30 new likes (so 230 in total). I want to see who additionally liked my post. Problem: Likes are not in chronological order, I can't figure out what logic is being used for sorting, it looks quite random. Browsing the 230 likes trying to find which ones are new would take too much time.

Is there any way to either:

- Show only the likes I have not seen yet, or
- Sort chronologically, or even better in reverse chronological order?

I am using the desktop webapp. Any solution is fine, even if it requires a add-on or some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see Likes in chronological order. They show it randomly. That is how they have featured it currently.

Check the Facebook API, if they have provided timestamp for Likes, you can write a script to help yourself.

Comment: An add-on could also simply store locally whose likes have been seen already.